# Creat temporay thumb image in PHP

Tags: php, thumbnails, temporary-files

Hey, i am looking for a method to creat temporay thumb file in PHP. Is there any way not to store the image on the server or delete them right after. What I am looking for is a solution like this: http://www.dig2go.com/index.php?shopbilde=772&type=1&size=120

Could some one explain to me how the php code behind this works? For the moment are am using a php code I found on the net for creation of thumb nails:

```
function createThumb($pathToImage, $pathToThumb, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight,    $saveNameAndPath)
{
   if(!file_exists($pathToImage))
   return false;

   else
   {
      //Load image and size
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImage);
      $width = imagesx($img);
      $height = imagesy($img);

      //Calculate the size of thumb
      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
      $new_height = $thumbHeight; //floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

      //Make the new thumb
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

      //Copy the old image and calculate the size
      imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

      //Save the thumb to jpg 
      imagejpeg($tmp_img, $saveNameAndPath);

      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this is old. just wondering if the answer was any good. Plus some hints on the usage. cheers

Comment: It was actually very helpfull, i rember it got it to work. But the code I used do I have no ide about where went. What are you having trouble with? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function createThumb($pathToImage, $pathToThumb, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight,    $saveNameAndPath)
    {
       if(!file_exists($pathToImage))
       return false;

```
   else
   {
      //Load image and size
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImage);
      $width = imagesx($img);
      $height = imagesy($img);

      //Calculate the size of thumb
      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
      $new_height = $thumbHeight; //floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

      //Make the new thumb
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

      //Copy the old image and calculate the size
      imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
      // sets the header and creates the temporary thumbnail
      // ideal for ajax requests / <img> elements
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
      imagejpeg($img);

      return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ini_set("memory_limit","12M"); to set memory limit in your script. You can extend it from 12 megabytes to maximum memory you have.

Generally 64M is good.